# Unity / Mirror second player has no authority on PlayerController

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, networking, unity3d-mirror

I am new to Mirror and facing this problem: In my board game I want to create some tokens when a client connects. This works fine with the first one, but when the second client tries to register, it says `"Trying to send command for object without authority. System.Void NetworkController::RegisterPlayer()"`. The API says, that auto spawned players are granted authority also automatically.

Thanks for your help!

```
public override void OnStartClient()
{
    base.OnStartClient();

    if (hasAuthority)
        NetworkClient.connection.identity.GetComponent<NetworkController>().CmdRegisterPlayer();        
}

[Command]
public void CmdRegisterPlayer()
{
    // do sth.
}
```

[Second Player Network Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6Bk0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, that my player controller script was a singleton and I did not know, that every clients player controller has to be in every other clients scene...